# How can I show just the 'error' without the 'print pay' statement at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello if i run this code and type letters in the input i get the error message but it also shows 'Pay none' I imagine it's because of the order? How can i get it so it just shows the 'Error' message? Thank you

```
def computepay():
    hrs=input('Hours:\n')
    rte=input('rte:\n')
    try:
        h=float(hrs)
        r=float(rte)
        if h>40:
            xp=((h-40)*(1.5*r))
            txp=xp+(40*r)
            return (txp)
        else:
            p=h*r
            return (p)
    except:
        print ('Error')
print ('Pay',computepay())
```

Comment: With `print('Pay',computepay())` the only way that won't be printed is if the function allows the error to propagate (or catches and reraises it or a new error). If you don't want to print anything when the function returns None, split up the function invocation and the printing and explicitly check for that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the `print()` statement when it throws an error then try exiting the code on the `except` block using `sys.exit()`

```
import sys
def computepay():
    hrs=input('Hours:\n')
    rte=input('rte:\n')
    try:
        h=float(hrs)
        r=float(rte)
        if h>40:
            xp=((h-40)*(1.5*r))
            txp=xp+(40*r)
            return (txp)
        else:
            p=h*r
            return (p)
    except:
        print ('Error')
        sys.exit(0)
print ('Pay',computepay())
```

```
Output:
Hours:
a
rte:
b
Error
```